# pandoc - markdown to man page tables not formatted (on msys2)

Tags: linux, markdown, msys, pandoc, manpages

I am trying to use pandoc (if someone has a better conversion program I am all ears, please not ruby-dependent) to convert markdown files into manpages. It works fine until I go to do a doc with a table. Here is my test doc:

```
% Author Man
% TEST(1) This is a test | Version .01
% 18-April-2016

# Header1

# Format

foo

+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| linenum-1 | two       | three     |
|===========+===========+===========+
| three     | four      | fove      |
| 6         | 7         | 8         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+

| linenum-1 | two       | three     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| three     | four      | fove      |
| 6         | 7         | 8         |

| linenum-1 | two       | three
|-----------|-----------|--------:
| three     | four      | fove
| 6         | 7         | 8

I WAS HERE

| linenum-1 | two       | three
|---        |---        |---
| three     | four      | fove
| 6         | 7         | 8

here is some text

_italics_

**bold**
```

I was using

```
pandoc.exe -s -f markdown -t man ~/test.md | man -p t -l -
```

(I tried with and without the `-p t` to force the `tbl` preprocessor) with the same result:

```
Author Man()                                                                        Author Man()

Header1
Format
       foo

       tab(@); lw(11.7n) lw(11.7n) lw(11.7n).  T{

       linenum-1 ===========+ three 6 T}@T{

       two ===========+ four 7 T}@T{

       three ===========+ fove 8 T}

       tab(@); l l l.  T{ linenum-1 T}@T{ two T}@T{ three T} _ T{ three T}@T{ four T}@T{ fove T}
       T{ 6 T}@T{ 7 T}@T{ 8 T}

       tab(@); l l r.  T{ linenum-1 T}@T{ two T}@T{ three T} _ T{ three T}@T{ four T}@T{ fove T}
       T{ 6 T}@T{ 7 T}@T{ 8 T}

       I WAS HERE

       tab(@); l l l.  T{ linenum-1 T}@T{ two T}@T{ three T} _ T{ three T}@T{ four T}@T{ fove T}
       T{ 6 T}@T{ 7 T}@T{ 8 T}

       here is some text

       italics

       bold

AUTHORS
       TEST(1) This is a test | Version .01.

                                          18-April-2016                             Author Man()
```

The raw output without piping it to `man` is:

```
.\"t
.\" Automatically generated by Pandoc 1.17.0.2
.\"
.TH "Author Man" "" "18\-April\-2016" "" ""
.hy
.SH Header1
.SH Format
.PP
foo
.PP
.TS
tab(@);
lw(11.7n) lw(11.7n) lw(11.7n).
T{
.PP
linenum\-1 ===========+ three 6
T}@T{
.PP
two ===========+ four 7
T}@T{
.PP
three ===========+ fove 8
T}
.TE
.PP
.TS
tab(@);
l l l.
T{
linenum\-1
T}@T{
two
T}@T{
three
T}
_
T{
three
T}@T{
four
T}@T{
fove
T}
T{
6
T}@T{
7
T}@T{
8
T}
.TE
.PP
.TS
tab(@);
l l r.
T{
linenum\-1
T}@T{
two
T}@T{
three
T}
_
T{
three
T}@T{
four
T}@T{
fove
T}
T{
6
T}@T{
7
T}@T{
8
T}
.TE
.PP
I WAS HERE
.PP
.TS
tab(@);
l l l.
T{
linenum\-1
T}@T{
two
T}@T{
three
T}
_
T{
three
T}@T{
four
T}@T{
fove
T}
T{
6
T}@T{
7
T}@T{
8
T}
.TE
.PP
here is some text
.PP
\f[I]italics\f[]
.PP
\f[B]bold\f[]
.SH AUTHORS
TEST(1) This is a test | Version .01.
```

With the `-d` flag I get a lot, but only the last bit seems applicable:

```
final search path = /mingw64/share/man:/usr/share/man
restore_cwd: 3 (null)
pre-processors `t' from command line
page_encoding = UTF-8
source_encoding = ISO-8859-1
roff_encoding = ISO-8859-1
Terminal width 102
Terminal width 102 not within cat page range [80, 80]
formatted_encoding = UTF-8
opening -
opened -
```

And the fun part...

Pandoc on my debian 8.3 box generated the same output, but manpages displays that fine on debian/linux.

For a comparison

### windows

- pandoc.exe 1.17.0.2
- man 2.7.4
- GNU tbl (groff) version 1.22.3

### linux

- pandoc 1.12.4.2 [linux]
- man 2.7.0.2

I've been reading through `man man` `man groff_man` `man tbl` etc for hours now and am no closer to solving this. Any ideas here would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thank you
-Eric

## Edit - 1

The issue is without a doubt `man` and associated `groff` system on windows/msys. The pandoc output works fine on linux.

I found and tried an alternative rendering program:

http://embedeo.org/ws/doc/man_windows/

Which has no issue display the output from pandoc with the format

```
mandoc.exe foo.man.1 | less
```

Trying again a more direct

```
cat foo.man.1 | nroff -mandoc -Tlatin1 | less
```

Has the exact same effect as calling `man -l -`

I then tried downloading the gnuwin32 binaries direct and had the same result again

```
cat foo.man.1 | Downloads/groff-1.20.1-bin/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tlatin1 | less
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well apparently I am a bit slow this week...

simplest fix imaginable, and I only wasted 3 days:

```
pandoc.exe -s -f markdown -t man ~/test.md | dos2unix.exe | man -l -
```

(the key being the introduction of **`dos2unix.exe`** into the mix)

Yields a beautiful:

```
Author Man()                                                                                                                                                                             Author Man()

Header1
Format
       foo

              linenum-1             two                   three
              ===========+          ===========+          ===========+
              three                 four                  fove
              6                     7                     8

       linenum-1   two    three
       ─────────────────────────
       three       four   fove
       6           7      8

       linenum-1   two    three
       ─────────────────────────
       three       four    fove
       6           7          8

       I WAS HERE

       linenum-1   two    three
       ─────────────────────────
       three       four   fove
       6           7      8

       here is some text

       italics

       bold

AUTHORS
       TEST(1) This is a test | Version .01.

                                                                                            18-April-2016                                                                                Author Man()
```